# Cant get last known location (from Android Developer's page)

Tags: android

I am using the following code from the Android Developers page, but I keep getting "cannot resolve symbol" for the following: `FusedLocationProviderClient`, `LocationServices`, `getLastLocation` and `OnSuccessListener`.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.lastknownlocation.lastknownlocation;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            // Logic to handle location object

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'`inside your gradle dependacies

Comment: Now I get "Call requires permission which may be rejected..." on `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`. Why?

Comment: You need to get permission from user to get location.

Comment: Look at here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#location_permissions